# How to get request variables in Yii 2 from encoded URL?

Tags: http, parameters, request, yii2

My question is quite basic but I can't figure it out - maybe I'm missing some basic concept here.

I'm creating a link URL in a menu like this:

```
['label' => Icon::show("newspaper") . Yii::t('app', 'News'), 'url' => ['site/index', ['section' => 'news']], 'options' => ['class' => 'mobile-menu']],
```

It generates the following URL (appears in the address bar):

```
http://localhost/websitename/web/site/index?1%5Bsection%5D=main
```

I am unable to extract GET variables from the URL using `Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('section')` - this is where I would need help. I'm either using this wrong or I need to do something prior or I'm generating the URLs in a bad way... who knows? :)

Note: it works if I manually type into the address bar like this:

```
http://localhost/websitename/web/site/index?section=main
```

So I'm thinking the URL encoding messes things up (in part)...

Many thanks in advance!
Andras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've nested the params in another array.
They just need to be `key => value`'s in the `url` array.

```php
['label' => Icon::show("newspaper") . Yii::t('app', 'News'), 'url' => ['site/index', 'section' => 'news'], 'options' => ['class' => 'mobile-menu']],
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a mistake from my side, not checking the docs. I thought by default that an "array" of GET params should be passed as an array... I thought wrong. :)